# Clickable words in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, user-interface

Is there a 3rd party library which allows contents of UILabel (words) to receive events (for example click, double click, etc)? I'm interested in distinguishing which word received an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zepplock I dont know about any 3rd party library, but try this link,

[UILabel touch and get the text where touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373053/uilabel-touch-and-get-the-text-where-touched)

I m not sure if the answer might help, but the user said that there is a sample code. so you can try it out.

Comment: It seems to be very close to what I need but it applies to the editable text, whereas I need it to be a static UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be dividing your string and then displaying that parts on different UIButtons.
But if you have a lot of text, then you probably need to check docs for Core Text. It will allow you to get coordinates of word/sentence/letter and then you can add some overlay (e.g. UIButton) that would receive touch events. Or you can override UIResponder methods and use gesture recognizers.