# UILabel UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I'm stuck in a problem now,I want to get the text be selectable,but the text had been put into a UILabel,so currently it's impossible for me to select,change the UILabel to UITextView is not a good choice for me now,since i just maintain the old code and only can make some little change on it,but the latest command need me to implement this function on UILabel,so anybody get any idea .or just give me some little instruction maybe good enough,thanks a lot

[Getting the word touched in a UILabel/UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview)
is not helpful

Comment: you want to edit text of label?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to a `UITextView` or `UITextField`.  It will be a smaller, easier change than trying to re-implement the selection UI that those classes already implement.  You can make the text view (or field) selectable but not editable by setting the view's `editable` property to NO.

Comment: thanks at first for your answer,but currently uitextfield isn't a good choice ,so how can i re-implement the selection-ui?dose anybody give me some idea,for i know that it's impossible for now to use the standard API to select the text on a uilabel

Comment: To reimplement the selection UI, you need to implement a bunch of touch handling and graphics.  It's a lot of work.  Maybe you should explain why you can't use `UITextField`.

Comment: there are two levels to display the post and it's replay,and the post have text,labels,images,hypelinks...,as the first level being touched ,the second level have the post stand at the top of the table followed by the replays,Unfortunately,now i need the post at the second level have the text be editable,if i use the textview or textfield at this level for the text,the layout be disordered,because all the layout had been calculated at the first level and all the text had been put into uilabel,so that's the problem

Comment: yes,i see it,it's problem in the choice to have the text in the label,then i want to get the label be editable,so thank you Rob for your concern.