# Tap gesture to part of a UITextView

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapResponse)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[_textView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

This will react to the entire UITextView, but is it possible to change it so that it only responds to when a certain part of the string in the UITextView is tapped? Like a URL for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot assign tap gesture to particular string in normal UITextView. You can probably set the dataDetectorTypes for UITextView.

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

If you want to detect only urls, you can assign to,

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Check the documentation for more details on this: [UIKit DataTypes Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html). Also check this [Documentation on UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/dataDetectorTypes)

**Update:**

Based on your comment, check like this:

```
- (void)tapResponse:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
     CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:_textView];
     NSLog(@"Tap Gesture Coordinates: %.2f %.2f", location.x, location.y);
     NSString *tappedSentence = [self lineAtPosition:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
     //use your logic to find out whether tapped Sentence is url and then open in webview
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441783/1730272), use:

```
- (NSString *)lineAtPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    //eliminate scroll offset
    position.y += _textView.contentOffset.y;
    //get location in text from textposition at point
    UITextPosition *tapPosition = [_textView closestPositionToPoint:position];
    //fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
    UITextRange *textRange = [_textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularitySentence inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
    return [_textView textInRange:textRange];
}
```

You can try with granularities such as, UITextGranularitySentence, UITextGranularityLine etc.. Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTokenizer_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextGranularity) here.

Comment: that will display the link, but the gesture will react to all of the textView

Comment: Yes. Once you tap on the link, it will open corresponding application based on the url scheme.

Comment: Yeah but with a URL it open in safari, with a UITapGesture, I was hoping to have it open in my UIWebView

Comment: Updated my answer. Check with that.

Comment: Cool will have a play with that and update my answer in a bit:-)

Comment: Try with different granularity options and you can update my answer with which ever worked for you. But this should guide you to right direction.

Comment: Yes this definitely put me on the right path thanks:-) I just work out the final few little bits.

Comment: Why do you remake the CGPoint in `tapResponse:`?