# How can I detect words in a UITextView that are touched over by a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm essentially trying to create a similar highlight feature in iBooks, where you can pan over a text with a single touch and the words become highlighted. This is without editing any text. The problem is that I can't detect what words in the uitextview are being panned over.

I tried using the method: [Get word from long tap in a word of UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349459/get-word-from-long-tap-in-a-word-of-uitextview). But this doesn't seem to detect a word when calling the method in a handlePanGesture method using the gesture's locationOfTouch:inView: as the "pos" argument, since this line...

```
 UITextRange * wr = [_tv.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPos withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
```

..returns nil.

Are there any other ways to go about doing this?

Comment: Make sure your tapPos is using the correct position relative to the frame-origin of your UITextView. Verify by logging...

Comment: Managed to figure it out. TapPos was correctly assigned position within the textview, but I incorrectly passed in self.view into the method thinking that it would refer to textview, which the gesture was assigned too. Really dumb mistake. But thanks for the help.