# Get word from tap in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get a word from a tap. The following function's `sender` is from the `UIGesture` on the `UITextView`, sentence.

```
- (IBAction)printWordSelected:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked");

    CGPoint pos = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    UITextView *_tv = sentence;

    NSLog(@"Tap Gesture Coordinates: %.2f %.2f", pos.x, pos.y);

    //eliminate scroll offset
    pos.y += _tv.contentOffset.y;

    //get location in text from textposition at point
    UITextPosition *tapPos = [_tv closestPositionToPoint:pos];

    //fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
    UITextRange * wr = [_tv.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPos withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];

    NSLog(@"WORD: %@", [_tv textInRange:wr]);
}
```

This is what I already have, but it prints the word out as NULL

Comment: Try changing pos to **pos = [sender locationInView:_tv]** and then remove the pos.y adjustment.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview/21577829#21577829

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Try changing pos to pos = [sender locationInView:_tv] and then remove the pos.y adjustment. – rmaddy"

Comment: This works well unless the UITextview is not scrolled. But when we scroll the textview, correct word is not printed.