# How to get range of characters from a tapped word UITextview

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextinput, uitextposition

I need to get the range of characters from a tapped word from a UITextView. I have set up a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my instance of `UITextView *tv`.

I currently have a solution that can tell me the *word* that was tapped, as described in this solution: [Get word from tap in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884520/get-word-from-tap-in-uitextview).

I need the range of characters of the word that was tapped, not just the word itself, preferably available in a way where I can access the start and end values as integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have used is:

```
int posOfSelected = [tv offsetFromPosition:tv.beginningOfDocument
                        toPosition:textRange.start];
```

I get the character index of the first letter of the tapped word, as an offset from the beginning of the document.