# Design like Instagram notifications (Especially someone mentioned you in a comment) with autolayout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints, instagram

In android, Instagram app notifications view have multi action like if we tap user image(left side) that go to another view, if we tap Instagram photo (right side) that go with different view and then in middle have few operations here example:

someone mentioned you in a comment yourname

someone(uibutton- with action- blue color) mentioned you in a comment(uilabel- no action- black color) yourname(uibutton- with action- blue color)

My app have same view like Instagram notification view left side (user profile image with uibutton action), right side image (like insta uploaded photo with uibutton action), in middle mixed with uilabel and uibuttons.

I not good at programming constraints. So here I didn't post any coding constraints :(

My constraints like:

[left side image] - leading superview - trailing middle view - constant height and width

[right side image] - trailing superview - leading middle view - constant height and width

[middle view] - leading left side image - trailing right side image - center y

in middle view have 3 elements in order 1stuibutton - uilabel - 2nduibutton - constant height

[1stuibutton] - leading superview - trailing uilabel - y - top to 5 - constant height - dynamic width

[2nduibutton] - trailing superview - leading uilabel - y - buttom to 5 - constant height - dynamic width

[uilabel] - trailing 2nduibutton - leading 1stuibutton - y - top to 5 - dynamic height

hope this constraints understandable :)

My Problem is uilabel number of line = 0 so that uilabel height only increased 2nduibutton won't join with uilabel last word.

So I tried nsattributedtext it's works only color different, I don't know how to set actions for that particular texts.

[image]

Comment: An screenshot or two could help understand.

Comment: Do you want screen shot with constraint or with nsattributedtext? Now I am using nsattributedtext so need time to update constraint screen shot @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Found a soultion for this issue

here link for what I get [stack over flow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15476078/3589771)

```
- (void)userTagsGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)recognizer.view;

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];

CGPoint tappedPosition = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);

//get location in text from textposition at point
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:tappedPosition];

//fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];

NSString *tappedSentence = [textView textInRange:textRange];

NSLog(@"%@",tappedSentence);
}
```

As usual design and got what I need maybe it will help others. :)