# Detecting touches on an underlying UITableViewCell and taps in attributed text of a UITextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, textkit

I use a `UITextView` that is attached to a `UITableViewCell` with a configuration as shown below:

```
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.tag = 1;
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.attributedText = attrText;    
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.editable = NO;
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
cell.topicAndDescriptionTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Now I would like to use text kit feature to detect taps on custom links in my attributed text (http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks) and `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to identify a drilldown if a customer clicks somewhere in the `UITableViewCell` where there is no custom link.

Unfortunately `[UITextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` makes the textview swallow all touches. What is the best approach to achieve this? I thought of writing a custom `UITextView` Class, and use `UITextView` delegates, but how can I then identify if the super class handles the press on a link already and to block a drilldown?

THX,

Jan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884520/get-word-from-tap-in-uitextview ?

Comment: @Larme - If I do it like that I still have the issue with the swallowed touches for the UITableView drilldown.. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to override hitTest and only return a hit view if the returned view is the one that is used for link buttons. In other cases return nil. Then the touch is passed to the table view instead and the scrolling keeps working.

Comment: Thx! will test this and provide feedback when I got it running!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I created my custom UITextView Class and override touchesBegan. Touches Began is only called if no link is clicked in UITextView. I played around with hitTest, but hitTest is called all the time and I can't determine if a link was touched or not inside the UITextView.