# Making a word in label trigger a method

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, uilabel

Is there a way or framework that could allow me to make clicking a word/words in a `UILabel` trigger a method? The ones I found elsewhere does not give me the option to do that, they only parse phone numbers, urls, events, etc.

**Edit:**

I forgot to add that the label is being created dynamically from some parsed data. So I'll also need to be able to do this dynamically.

**Edit:**

Also, I'll need the word selected as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a uibutton on that word (above the label), and create button event.

Comment: I forgot some additional detail in my post. It's updated now.

Comment: you can find the location of the word as: [string rangeOfString:@"Word"].location

Comment: I actually need the word itself, not the location of the word.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create dynamic custom button with following code

   ```
   UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

   [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x - 5, lbl.frame.origin.y - 5, lbl.frame.size.width + 10, lbl.frame.size.height + 10)];

   [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   [self.view addSubview:btn]; *where lbl = <YOUR DYNAMIC LABLE>*
   ```
2. Give a method for touch up Inside, like stated below

   ```
   [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(<YOUR_METHOD_NAME_TO_INVOKE>) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```

create a custom button with no image.keep your lable in front of it. & integrate method delegates to the custom button. You will find the same as you want..

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: I forgot some additional detail in my post. It's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

See below link:
[Get Word From UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview)

By getting word from UILabel you can apply condition on what word you got by touching on UILabel.And trigger action on words that you are getting.

May this will help you..

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll take a look at this and see how it goes.