# How to create UILabel with clickable first word

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I want to create label in iOS, can anyone help me to make the first word of the label's text bold and clickable.
The label displays username and its comment and the first word is always the username.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: be more specific, post some code that u tried

Comment: only the first word should respond to user interaction?

Comment: yes only first word respond to user interaction.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview/21577829#21577829 . It will give you tapped word of `UILabel` you can simply compare it with first word of `UILabel`.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose more elegant solution will be using [TTTAttributedString](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or similar.

**Example:**

[image: simple demo]

**Output:**

```
2013-03-10 07:16:54.429 ClickableUILabel-SO[4770:c07] UserName clicked
Address:    {
    comment = "Your comment.";
    userName = user2126537;
}
2013-03-10 07:16:55.460 ClickableUILabel-SO[4770:c07] UserName clicked
Address:    {
    comment = "Another comment.";
    userName = nsgulliver;
}
```

**Key point:**

```
...

NSRange userNameRange = [text rangeOfString: userName];

...

label.delegate = self;
[label addLinkToAddress: @{
           @"userName" : userName,
            @"comment" : comment
    }
                  withRange: userNameRange];

...

- (void) attributedLabel: (TTTAttributedLabel *)label
didSelectLinkWithAddress: (NSDictionary *)addressComponents
{
    NSLog(@"UserName clicked\nAddress:\t%@", addressComponents);
}
```

[**Complete source code**](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/so/ClickableUILabel-SO.zip)

Note that you should open `xcworkspace` in Xcode/AppCode because I'm using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) here.

Hope it helps.

BR.
Eugene

Comment: how can i detect the #tags and @usernames using  TTTAttributedString

Comment: It does not work with compile error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I've just updated the sources, please use xcworkspace file instead of xcodeproj.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`  for making `UILabel` clickable. Use `UIView`  and add `UILabel` as subviews to that

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod:)];
[yourLabelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[yourLabelView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

One way of making first word `clickable` is to take out the first word from the label using the string method  and store it in another label and use the above code to make it clickable

```
NSArray* wordArray = [yourLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
NSString* firstWord = [wordArray objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Comment: It wont work for 1st character. Full label will be clickable.

Comment: yes you are right, but this is the way to make a label `clickable`

Comment: If the label text will be constant create a blank view and place over top of the first word, then attach the gesture recognizer to that.

Comment: This is the way to make label clickable, I agree.But the question doesn't demand that, have a better look at the title itself once more. @Foram Mukund Shah 's answer can be used.

Comment: what is the point then if he has to use button. he could just button this question would not make sense, he asked about Label.

Answer (score 2):

- Make a custom button, which will contain the first word of your
  username, make text bold.
- Take a label, just beside the custom button & write the rest part of your username other than the first word.
- On the click event of the custom button, do whatever you want to do..

Hope this will be clear to you.

Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

labels seems to be difficult. Ypu can use a view. add a button and lable on that side by side and add 1st character to button and others to label.