# IOS Multiple line Label floating around a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-text

I am trying fit an `UIButton` and an `UILabel` on the same line. If the `UILabel` is larger it will then wrap around the `UIButton` to the next line.

For example,

[image]

In this case, Kobe Bryant would be the `UIButton` which is **clickable**. and the rest of the text are `UILabel`.

The thing is that The `UIButton` is a variable and the width changes. I spent an entire day researching on google and stackoverflow and cannot come up with an answer.

If any of you can point me to the right direction, I'll be really appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this answer, you can change it to use the frame for the button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20033752/2043580

Comment: You should use a non-editable TextView as UILabel does not support exclusion paths

Comment: How do I calculate the width of the UIButton which is known only at runtime

Comment: You can use button.frame to get the frame at runtime.

Comment: you keep the text in the webview and give the 'kobe bryant' as link.I have faced the same issue and I spent hours same as you

Comment: but Kobe Bryant supposes to open up another UIViewController via a segue

Comment: call the method in the delegate method and see the post of neenu

Comment: Resolving. Trying to disable scroll view and use dynamic height.

Comment: Because the webview may end up 3 or 4 lines, I want the height to be dynamic any tips?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64213/discussion-between-user3081516-and-ramesh-muthe).

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293426/how-to-create-uilabel-with-clickable-first-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString    *link = @"<a href=\"movetonextscreen\" style=\"text-decoration:none; color : #000000;\"><b>Kobe Bryant</b></a>";
NSString    *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ your text", link];
UIWebView   *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

In the delegate method you do this

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
}
}
```

After loading the text now fix the height of webview to the content

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect newBounds = <webView>.bounds;
    newBounds.size.height = <webView>.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    <webView>.bounds = newBounds;
}
```

Disable scrolling

```
self.<WebView>.scrollView.scrollEnabled=FALSE;
```

Comment: When I have the webView as 3 lines, after I click on the Button it shrinked to 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a web view instead of UIButton and UILabel (disable the scrolling ).
Load the text in the webview as ,

```
webview.delegate=self;
[webview loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body><a href=\"name_identifier\"><b>Kobe Bryant</b></a> is a very good basketball player who is coming off an serious injury.</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

Listen for the URL

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([[[aRequest URL] absoluteString] isEqual:@"name_identifier"]){

        //TODO:Do the steps to call when press on the name
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

For performing the Segue action

1. Remove the segue from UIButton
2. ctrl+drag from the source UIViewController to destination UIViewController.
3. select "push".
4. Give an identifier to the segue.

And add the below line to go to the next view controller. 
(before `return NO;` in the above code)

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue_id" sender:self];
```

You can disable the scrolling of the web view as,

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

And can calculate the dynamic height as,

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320,568); //change as you wish

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [contentString sizeWithFont:fontUsed 
                        constrainedToSize: maximumSize 
                        lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
```

Set the new height as,

```
[webview sizeThatFits: expectedLabelSize];
```

or

```
CGRect newFrame = webview.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
webview.frame = newFrame;
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The UIButton suppose to opens up a segue to another view controller as oppose to another webview

Comment: It is working fine. But how do I disable the scrolling and use dynamic height. Because it may be 1, 2 or more lines depending on the length of the text

Comment: Hi Neenu, thanks alot. Everything is working except the dynamic height. I believe sizeWithFont is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can UITextView with attributed String setting to do this trick for you. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22551123/641062) for how to do this.

**Another Approach** :

If you want to add a weblink to textview you can use following code snippet.

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://your link" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
yourTextView.attributedText = str;
```

To detect if a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4338011/641062) is tapped.

Combining the ideas above you can set a custom URL say `http://linktapped`. When you tap this you would get a call in App delegate. You can check if it your URL  and do appropriate action needed(Instead of opening safari).

Comment: Opps missed it. Edited now.