# Tap Gesture on part of UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, uitextinput

I could successfully add tap gestures to a part of UITextView with the following code:

```
UITextPosition *pos = textView.endOfDocument;// textView ~ UITextView

for (int i=0;i<words*2-1;i++){// *2 since UITextGranularityWord considers a whitespace to be a word

    UITextPosition *pos2 = [textView.tokenizer positionFromPosition:pos toBoundary:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft];
    UITextRange *range = [textView textRangeFromPosition:pos toPosition:pos2];
    CGRect resultFrame = [textView firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range ];

    UIView* tapViewOnText = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:resultFrame];
    [tapViewOnText addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(targetRoutine)]];
    tapViewOnText.tag = 125;
    [textView addSubview:tapViewOnText];

    pos=pos2;
}
```

I wish to imitate the same behaviour in a `UILabel`. The issue is, `UITextInputTokenizer` (used to tokenize the individual words) is declared in `UITextInput.h`, and only `UITextView` & `UITextField`conform to `UITextInput.h`; `UILabel` does not.
Is there a workaround for this ??

Comment: hi friend, have you checked the user interaction behaviour of UILabel, because by default userinteraction is NO of UIlabel, you will have to set it YES.Let me know is it working or not.!!!

Comment: Action on an entire UILabel is not an issue, it's 'part' of UILabel.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview/21577829#21577829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel and add a link to the label. When the link is pressed you get a action, so part of the label click works only thing you have to would be customizing the link part of the label. I tried this in the past and it worked flawlessly but my client was not interested in using a third party component so duplicated this functionality using UIWebView and HTML.

Comment: Finally settled on TTTAttributedLabel. It turns out to be as heavy as a UITextView.
:(

Comment: TTTAttributedLabel has height issues. Especially when it comes to emoji.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Let your label be `label` :

```
  //add gesture recognizer to label
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
  [label addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
  //setting a text initially to the label
  [label setText:@"hello world i love iphone"];

 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGRect rect = label.frame;
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, touchPoint)) {
    NSLog(@"Hello world");
}
}
```

**Clicking on the first half** of label will work (It gives log output). Not the other half.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer - You can create your own `CGRect newRect` based on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a light-weighted library specially for links in UILabel [FRHyperLabel](https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel).

To achieve an effect like this:

*[Lorem](http://www.google.com) ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. [Pellentesque](http://www.google.com) quis [blandit](http://www.google.com) eros, sit amet vehicula justo. Nam at urna neque. [Maecenas](http://www.google.com) ac sem eu sem porta dictum nec vel tellus.*

use code:

```cs
//Step 1: Define a normal attributed string for non-link texts
NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis blandit eros, sit amet vehicula justo. Nam at urna neque. Maecenas ac sem eu sem porta dictum nec vel tellus.";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]};

label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:string attributes:attributes];


//Step 2: Define a selection handler block
void(^handler)(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring) = ^(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring){
    NSLog(@"Selected: %@", substring);
};


//Step 3: Add link substrings
[label setLinksForSubstrings:@[@"Lorem", @"Pellentesque", @"blandit", @"Maecenas"] withLinkHandler:handler];
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a non-editable UITextView instead of a UILabel. Of course this may or may not be a suitable solution depending on your exact needs.

Comment: UITextViews are out of question. I can only use UILabels.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer, you can make the UITextView behave like UILabel.

Answer (score -3):

This is basic code for how can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your control;

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];        
[MyLabelName addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];        
[self.view addSubView:MyLabelName]
```

This is method that call when you tapped your `MyLabelName`;

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UILabel *)myLabel
{
    // do your stuff;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but i do not need a gesture on the entire label, just part of it.