# color change in texts of UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

i am novice in iPhone.

I have a textView. I am changing the background Color of selected texts in text View.

But problem is that when I am selecting more than 1 line in textView ,only first line color is being changed , not other lines color.

so can anyone tell me about this how can I change background color of all texts which i m selecting.??

```
 tagValue = textView.tag;

    NSRange r = textView.selectedRange;
 UITextRange     *selectedRange = [textView selectedTextRange];

    if (!selectedRange)
        return;

    CGRect result1 = [textView firstRectForRange:selectedRange];
    frame_selectedText = result1;


self.str_selected =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(r.location, r.length)]];
 UIButton  *btnView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnView setFrame:result1];

 [btnView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonColorClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0f/255.0f green:248.0f/255.0f blue:188.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5];

    [textView addSubview:btnView];
```

Comment: Can you show us some code, as how you're actually trying to set the colours ?

Comment: i added my code , dis is the way by which i m trying to set color ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that `firstRectForRange` will give you a rectangle that will not cover more than 1 line. As long as the text/selected text remains in one line, the rect will cover that.

Reason being: Imagine you select text that spans to a line and a half. So when you select the text, the selection color will show you that the selection boundary is not a rectangle. It is more like an inverted L. Hence, a **single** rect cannot cover it.

- If you want to highlight just the selected text, you will have to use multiple rects. See my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827035/tap-gesture-on-part-of-uilabel). I have covered multiple lines, and words with different rectangles. You can set a color and transparency (`alpha`) to give a feeling of *highlighting*. But the drawback here would be, you will not be able to interact with that text.
- If you want to create a single rectangle that covers all of your selected text, then it will cover text succeeding the selected text, but you can work with a single rectangle. For this you will have to use `firstRectForRange` twice. Once on the first word selected, and second on the first word selected in the *last* line of selected text. The use `MAX` and `MIN` to create a single rect that covers all your text.

**Alternate method**
`UITextView`s support `AttributedText`s. With this you can set text of `UITextView` with a string with multiple attributes (bold, italic, colored text, colored background etc). Use `NSMutableAttributedStrings` to store your text. Add attributes like this:

```
[myAttriButedText addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:UIColorFromRGB(0x333333) range:NSMakeRange(0, [myAttriButedText length])];
```

And set the text of `UITextView` using `setAttributedText`, or `textView.attributedText =`. This way, you easily add a background color on your text, without the hassles of all the above mentioned. But if you want more that just the attributes supported by `NSAttributedString`s, you will have to use above mentioned methods.

Comment: hmm.. i try your code.. beacause i'v used NSMutableAttributedString , and problem is that , i dont know y, its nt calling its instance methods

Comment: Instance methods of `UITextView`? What happens? Does it crash, or you cannot call the instance methods of textView.text?

Comment: And can u please tell me ??in your code what is 'words' in this line                                            for (int i=0;i<words*2-1;i++) is it total no. of words in selected text?

Comment: No,instance method of NSMutableAttributedString , when i m creating its object and try to call its instance method , like addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:UIColorFromRGB(0x333333) range:NSMakeRange(0, [myAttriButedText length])]   , i get a warning about "this instance method is not existed .. " something like that

Comment: Yes. This is because UIColorFromRGB is a macro i defined in my code. My mistake not pointing it out before. Either use :
`#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]`

or use a simple `UIColor` like `[UIColor blueColor]`

Comment: Bro your code also not working. :( anyway thanks for helping.