# Detect the tappabe word on UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

i am having the sentence like "i am **john doe** . i am living in **South Africa** . My friend name is **john mouse** ".

I can highlight the words by using attributed strings. Now the problem is to detect the name of the persons. i can detect the individual word using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview/21577829#21577829) sample. but if i tap on "john" (first). how to detect i am tapping john doe 's first name?

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how you know whether `john` is a first name? That requires linguistic knowledge. If, though, you just want to know whether you tapped the `john` that starts at character 5, then you can use the top answer in the link you provided.

Comment: no. if i tap the text john, i want to detect its full name is john doe or john mouse . thats is my problem

Comment: Do you have a dictionary of names, or a natural-language extractor? That's what you need.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, when you tap words? You should look into [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). It has the data detector types you want, and further it gives you the flexibility to invoke your own methods on tap on the words.

Comment: +1 something like `TTTAttributedLabel` is what you want.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer and Dima sorry, really i dont know how to do. can y pls help.