# NSAttributedString click event in UILabel using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Suppose I have an AttributedString: "Already have an account? Sign in!".

I am placing this String in UILabel. Now when a user clicks on "Sign in!", the current viewController should go to another viewController or some function should be called while clicking on sign in.

Any code or suggestion should be fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no need to use a separate gesture recognizer as some of the answers state. Instead, you can use attributed text in combination with the `UITextViewDelegate`'s [`textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview?language=objc) method to achieve this, ex:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Already have an account? ")
        text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
        
        let selectablePart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sign in!")
        selectablePart.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(0, selectablePart.length))
        // Add an underline to indicate this portion of text is selectable (optional)
        selectablePart.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0,selectablePart.length))
        selectablePart.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, selectablePart.length))
        // Add an NSLinkAttributeName with a value of an url or anything else
        selectablePart.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "signin", range: NSMakeRange(0,selectablePart.length))
        
        // Combine the non-selectable string with the selectable string
        text.append(selectablePart)
        
        // Center the text (optional)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
        
        // To set the link text color (optional)
        textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]
        // Set the text view to contain the attributed text
        textView.attributedText = text
        // Disable editing, but enable selectable so that the link can be selected
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        // Set the delegate in order to use textView(_:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange)
        textView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        // **Perform sign in action here**
        
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: `textView.delegate = self` is giving error
 **Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextViewDelegate?'**

Comment: @RishuAgrawal Did you add `UITextViewDelegate` to the view controller as in the first line of my code: `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {` ?

Comment: How could  I identify If there are two links and based on click If i want to apply different actions..

Comment: The question is about UILabel NOT UITextView. Not sure why this answer was accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Label you can use a textview to open a View Controller or make substring clickable.

1. Create an attribute for the string which you want to make clickable

   ```
   let linkAttributes = [
       NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue
       ] as [String : Any]
   ```
2. Make your string an attributed string

   ```
   let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"My name is Jarvis")
   attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(5, 10))
   ```

   You can give your custom range here.
3. Add an *attributed* text to your textview

   ```
   YourTextView.attributedText = attributedString
   ```
4. Then implement the following delegate method of textview to implement interaction for a URL

   ```
   func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
       // Here write your code of navigation
       return false
   }
   ```
5. If you want to do it with label, click see *[How can I make a clickable link in an NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-to-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a)*.

Answer (score 4):

Language update based on [@Lindsey Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574043) answer :)

### **Swift 4**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Already have an account? ")
        text.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font,
                          value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length))
        
        let interactableText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sign in!")
        interactableText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font,
                                      value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: interactableText.length))
        
        // Adding the link interaction to the interactable text
        interactableText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link,
                                      value: "SignInPseudoLink",
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: interactableText.length))
        
        // Adding it all together
        text.append(interactableText)
        
        // Set the text view to contain the attributed text
        textView.attributedText = text
        
        // Disable editing, but enable selectable so that the link can be selected
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        
        //Code to the respective action
        
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the (significant) difference(s)?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to your label/view, or you can embed a link with a custom URL protocol into your attributed string, use a UITextView, and turn on link detection. You would then need to implement the UITextView delegate method for responding to links.

I have a demo project called [**DatesInSwift**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/DatesInSwift) (link) on GitHub that implements clickable links in a UITextView. Take a look at the `UITextView` delegate method `textView(_:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange)` in `ViewController.swift`. That's the method that tells the text view that it should respond to the URL.

Then you have to implement a UIApplicationDelegate method to handle the URL. The sample app uses `application(_:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation)`, which was deprecated in iOS 9. For new development you should use `application(_:openURL:options:)` instead.

You will also need to add a `CFBundleURLTypes` / `CFBundleURLSchemes` entry to your info.plist to register a custom URL scheme (like `myompany.myapp.loginURL`) in order for clicking on an embedded URL to invoke your app.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 and Xcode 11**

Using a TextView it's much easier:

```
func setupContactUsInTextView() {
    let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Contact us at email ")
    text.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font,
                      value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length))

    let interactableText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "contact@abc.com")
    interactableText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font,
                                  value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: interactableText.length))


    interactableText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link,
                                  value: "contact@abc.com",
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: interactableText.length))


    text.append(interactableText)


    contactUsTextView.attributedText = text
    contactUsTextView.textAlignment = .center
    contactUsTextView.isEditable = false
    contactUsTextView.isSelectable = true
    contactUsTextView.delegate = self
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    print("open website here...")
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use UITextView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let attribute:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Already have an account? Sign in!", attributes: ["Tag" : true])
        textView.attributedText = attribute

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.textTapped(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func textTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let textView:UITextView = recognizer.view as! UITextView

        // Location of the tap in text-container coordinates
        let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
        var location:CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(textView)

        location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
        location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top

        var distance:CGFloat?
        // Find the character that's been tapped on
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: &distance!)
        if characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length{
            var range:NSRange?
            let value = textView.attributedText.attribute("Tag", atIndex: characterIndex, effectiveRange: &range!)
            if value {
               // add your code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RishuAgrawal: You can disable the edition of a `UITextView`, and customize it too looks like a `UILabel`.

Comment: Why use a tap gesture when you could simply use `NSLinkAttributeName`?

Comment: Can you explain how to use that?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. There are a fair number of steps.

Answer (score -9):

You can apply tapGesture to the label.

Create tap gesture recognizer:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "YOUR_METHOD:")
```

Add gesture recognizer to label:

```
YOUR_LABEL.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Perform your tasks in this method:

```
func YOUR_METHOD(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    // Perform your operations here.
}
```

Comment: and set `YOUR_LABEL.userInteractionEnabled = true`.

Comment: But this is calling method for the whole string, not just "Sign in!"

Comment: Then simply use two labels and add tapgesture to signIn label.

Comment: @VishalSonawane : you're right, but I want this using single label.

Comment: Then have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview/21577829#21577829 and perform your actions when your word matches to Sign In(you will understand what I mean to say after going through that link).

Comment: The Answer is for whole string. we need the touch event for particular string.