# Label shows the html data and make image and link clickable by swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a html data in my label, and how to make them clickable.
I can show my html data successful, but I don't know how to convert them.
Have any good suggestion to me?
Thanks

[htmlData content here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1My5TqlwvZ5afLItOYEdfqFkRlgP-sWKx)

This is my label code:

```
let htmlData = ""

do {
        let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(
            data: htmlData.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)
        self.label.attributedText = attrStr
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

[image: pic1]

Comment: Use a `UITextView`, not a `UILabel`. `UILabel` are not meant to be clickable. You can make it, but it's kind of tricky, and there are already plenty of solution in CocoaPods/GitHub/CocoaControls, etc. The easier way is to use a `UITextView` and with small modifications, it can looks like a UILabel for the user.

Comment: Sorry ,have any sample to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString click event in UILabel using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565603/nsattributedstring-click-event-in-uilabel-using-swift)

Comment: sorry, I dont know how duplicate. Just string link I know how to do. But my link like my picture is in my html data string. I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Label may not detect hyperlinks, but "webView" does.

```
webView.loadHTMLString(dataHtmlString, baseURL: nil)
```