# iOS Accessibility: How to Increase the Touch Target size for AttributedString in a Label or TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility

### How to increase the touch receive area of an attributed string?

Given that a TextView with "View privacy settings and legal disclaimer". Where "privacy settings" and "legal disclaimer" are the attributed strings created in similar fashion as following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574043/12413715

```
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = .center
    footerAttributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: AppConstants.Tokens.Font.default,
                                          NSAttributedString.Key.font: SFProText.regular.of(size: 13),
                                          NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style],
                                         range: NSRange(location: 0, length: footerString.count))
     /// .... and so on
```

How to increase the height of the touch detection area for meeting accessibility guidelines on iOS (having minimum 44 px for interactive button heights)?

- ContentInsets doesn't work.
- Increasing the Font size wouldn't get approved by UX design team.

Thanks in advance!