# Detect tap on specific part of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I'm developing an instagram clone and I'm trying to dealing with user interact with a photo caption feature in `Home Feed` screen.
[image: example]

I want if a user tap on `username`, controller will push `ProfileViewController` or if user tap on `caption`, controller will push `CommentsViewController`.
Thanks for any suggest!

Comment: So you want to have one button that causes different IBActions depending on where the button is pressed?

Comment: You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577829/1140335)

Comment: @swiftcoder yes, button or label. I just guess that instagram using a button with differents NSAttributed because when I long press on it, it looks pretty close like when I do on button

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways.

You can attach a gesture and if you tap on a specific part of the frame, then do one thing.

```
func tapMethod(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //on label
    let touch = tap.locationInView(button)
    If(label.frame.contains(touch)) {
        //....
    }
    //not on label
    Else {
        /....
    }
}
```

Or you can add 2 tap gestures, one on the label and one on the button, then you can override

```
func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
    with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
```

This will allow you to touch on the button’s subviews if necessary as well click on the button’s actions if necessary. Here is a good example. https://medium.com/@nguyenminhphuc/how-to-pass-ui-events-through-views-in-ios-c1be9ab1626b. It reduces the coupling of code and allows for different pieces to come together. This is the hardest route but in my opinion, has the greatest benefit of allowing easiest movement and flow of code

Answer (score 0):

Use tag of *label* to find which *label*

```
titleLabel.tag = 1
captionLabel.tag = 2
```

then use `touchesBegan`

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    // to find cell index. use super view of label

    if let label = touch.view as! UILabel {

     if label.tag == 1 {
        // Move to profile screen
     } else if label.tag == 2 {
       // Move to comments screen
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign tags to each of your buttons in `cellforRow` Method like `cell.button1.tag = 1 ...` and attach a *commonEvent* to your *buttons* and detect which button is tapped by `sender.tag == 1 { }` and so on ..