# How to extract sub-string from UILabel based on finger pressed location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel which contains text.

Once I press on this UILabel, I want to extract one word from the location where my finger pressed.

I've searched a bit on internet, but have no clue about how to implement it.

Does anyone here know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know about the location thing, but you can access your label text like: "yourLabel.text", or the work around would be to add the button on label with text on them.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373053/uilabel-touch-and-get-the-text-where-touched) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811909/getting-the-word-touched-in-a-uilabel-uitextview) questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once I press on this UILabel, I want to extract one word from the
>   location where my finger pressed.

That's not something that's going to be easy to do with UILabel. UILabel is meant to be a simple way to put static text on the screen; it doesn't provide features that would let you determine the frames of individual words.

You'll probably be better off creating your own view for this. You'll want to dig into Core Text to lay out and draw the text. Core Text is a lot more complicated than just using a simple UILabel, but it gives you the information and control you'll need to determine where each word is drawn on the screen. Your view can use that information to map touches to words.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just make each individual word a separate label, so that all you have to do is add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the label and grab the text from it when it's touched.

If you want to do it with one label, though, here's some pseudocode of a way that could work:

1. Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the label. When touched, get the location of the touch.
2. Use NSString's `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font` method to get the size of the label's entire string (let's call this `stringSize`).
3. Compare `stringSize.width` to the width of your label to figure out where the text begins (if your label is center or right aligned, this might not be at the label's starting X coordinates). ie. `startingX = label.width - stringSize.width / 2`.
4. Now use NSString's `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` method to separate the string in your label into each word, with the space character as the delimiter. Let's store this into an array called `wordsAr`.
5. Create a variable, `currentXPos`, and initialize it to `startingX`.
6. Now create a for loop that goes through each word in `wordsAr`, calculates the size of that word using `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font`, and adds it to `currentXPos`. When `currentXPos` >= the x location of your touch value, you've found the word that you tapped on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTTAttributedLabel in the following link: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Define your clickable texts as Links for the Label, then you'll get exactly what you need.