# Click on UILabel and perform action

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple problem, I have a string like "#my#name#is#umesh#verma" and assign to a UITableview cell label,

```
cell.detaillabel.text = @"#my#name#is#umesh#verma";
```

My Problem is how to get each word name when I click on single item.
 If I click on #umesh then I get "umesh" word..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373053/uilabel-touch-and-get-the-text-where-touched

Comment: You can Dynamically generate multiple label or buttons according to number of names. Separate string by # so you will get array of words. In for loop add button or label dynamically.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but I'm facing some problem when I generate multiple buttons and I need to reload table then  these components are added in all cells while adding components as.. [cell.detaillabel.contentview addsubview:[uilabel]];

Answer (score 0):

More better solution is add custom label which supports touches. For example [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) supports touches on links.

Main task is get notification when user touch a word and to identify the word.

You can add URLs (with special format) to any word and subscribe to a notification when user click it (as delegate to the label). For example you can create this URL for "word":

touchscheme://word

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked about how to perform an action when clicking on a UILabel. However, I experienced that with UITextView. You can use "NSLinkAttributeName" to do that.

Basically, from your original string, try to find the range of string that you need to trigger actions. Then add a link value.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:yourString];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:range];
[textView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Set delegate to your textView and handle the following method

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
// You can retrive your string here or perform an action
return YES;
```

}

Hope this would be helpful for you.